# What Exception to throw when thread exits unexpectedly?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have a worker thread which, when it terminates, signals an event. This event is then marshalled over to the main thread to notifiy it of the worker thread's termination. When the worker thread encounters an unhandled exception, I want this exception to be handled by the main thread's error handling system. Therefor, the worker thread sets a property indicating its unexpected termination, and saves the exception in another property, then signals the event and exits.

After the event has been marshalled over to the main thread, I want to throw a new exception with the original exception set as the inner exception. My question is: what should the type of this new Exception be? Is there a specific System.somethingException for this kind of situation, should I Design my own Exception class for this specific situation, or would throwing a standard System.Exception with a proper message be considered appropriate?

C#-psuedo code:

```
class MyThread
{
    public TerminationState Termination { get; private set; }
    public Exception UncaughtException { get; private set; }

    public delegate void ThreadTerminatedDelegate(MyThread thread);
    public event ThreadTerminatedDelegate ThreadTerminated;

    private void run()
    {
        try
        {
            doSomeWork();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            UncaughtException = e;
            Termination = TerminationState.AbortOnException;
            ThreadTerminated(this);
            return;
        }
        Termination = TerminationState.NormalTermination;
        ThreadTerminated(this);
    }
}

class MainThread
{
    private MyThread myThread = new MyThread();

    private void run()
    {
        myThread.ThreadTerminated += handleTermination;
        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void handleTermination(MyThread thread)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            MyThread.ThreadTerminatedDelegate cb = new MyThread.ThreadTerminatedDelegate(handleTermination);
            BeginInvoke(cb, new object[] { thread });
        }
        else
        {
            if (thread.Termination == TerminationState.AbortOnException)
            {
                if (isFatal(thread.UncaughtException))
                    throw new Exception("", thread.UncaughtException); //what to do here?
                else
                    fixTheProblem();
            }
            else
            {
                //normal wrapping up
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say that it depends on what the thread is doing. Actually I don't like AggregateException that flat everything to a generic error so to swallow the original exception for something else...doesn't look such good idea. I'd clone it (to keep original stack trace) and I would rethrow it. But it's just my opinion...

Comment: What exactly do you hope to happen when you throw the exception again?  The 99% odds are that your program will crash.  Which is a Good Thing, something didn't get done and you have no hope of getting it done.  But then, just don't bother to catch the exception in the first place.  It will crash as well but at least you'll get a better diagnostic and don't have to write useless code.

Comment: @Adriano Instead of cloning and rethrowing, couldn't you just use `throw;`? That keeps the original stack trace, right?

Comment: @HansPassant Well the original reason to capture the exception is because the MainThread could modify a shared resource in such a way that the worker thread would fail, but this wouldn't actually be a problem. Of course, this would be a very ugly solution to that case, and I've already solved it another way. Still, I envision situations where the failure of the worker thread isn't that problematic, I might just start a new worker thread, for example. In those cases, I don't want my program to crash, but in other cases I do, so I need to rethrow the error, hence my question as to how.

Comment: If it is not a problem then you also don't have to bother rethrowing the exception.

Comment: @HansPassant of course. But like I said, in other cases I can't fix the problem, so I do need to rethrow the exception, and THAT's what the question is about.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you hope to happen when you rethrow it.  You'll have to be specific about that.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure, we don't see his whole program. _Probably_ he does some clean-up in the thread then he'll log it in the main thread and it'll perform more clean up. Finally someone else may handle the error from main thread and decide if application must be terminated or not. Anyway I agree that if it'll simply go unhandled then application **must** crash and exact exception type is not so important then.

Comment: @JSQuareD you can't just `throw;` because you're not inside a `catch` clause. Moreover **exact** stack trace is lost when you re-throw an exception (it'll be replaced with stack trace of the line where the throw is).

Comment: Seems like a `System.ApplicationException` that includes a message saying something like, "Unexpected thread termination, see inner exception" would be appropriate.

Comment: @JimMischel to crash application even `FormatException` works but `ApplicaitonException` should be used for non fatal errors. I would throw the same original exception, it seems to work like a catch/throw pattern but it just can't use `throw` because of application design. JSQuareD why don't you give to your thread a "fault handler" (provided by caller in main thread) to call in case of error? It may decide to throw or not (and thread itself may always abort).

Comment: @Adriano The fault handler merely changes the moment at which the fault is handled. (In fact, since the marshalling will be asynchronous, this difference wouldn't matter). Throwing the same original exception might work, but then there's little indication that the error actually occurred in a different thread.

Comment: With a fault handler you won't rethrow caught exception, you just **delegate** decision to someone else (but you abort thread) . Original location comes from stack trace (and inner exceptions) anyway you don't have to throw the same instance, just the same _type_ (with appropriate error message, maybe combined with original one).

Comment: @Adriano But if this delegate decides it can't handle the problem it will still have to throw an exception, which leaves me in exactly the same spot I'm in now. On any rate, I think I'll just go with `throw new Exception(thread.Name + " terminated unexcpectedly. Error: " + thread.UncaughtException.Message, updater.UncaughtException);`. Or a specific type of exception if I recognize the exception.

Comment: @Adriano BTW, although there is a specific case, I'm looking for a general solution, which is why I might seem a little vague... ;)

Comment: Yes I, understand. I would rethrow the original one (from the handler) or just drop it (so you'll even have the right stack trace). But it looks like you need a pretty general solution (kind of application block for exception handling)

Comment: I assume there is good reason not to, but I have to ask, why not implement this logic using TPL? It has built in exception handling and propagation logic designed to address scenarios exactly like this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Comment: @odysseus.section9 Actually, I'm still learning the ropes when it comes to C# and Multithreading, so there wasn't a good reason not to. But if I understood correctly, using TPL would mean the exception would only be handled when I await the task. The thread I'm talking about runs in the background the entire time, so error handling would get pushed back to when I exit the application, which is undesirable. In the system I described, an event is fired as soon as an unhandled exception has occured, which is much better for debugging purposes. Is there a way to do this using TPL?

Comment: @JSQuareD Yes, I believe so. I will try to put an answer together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can perform all necessary exception handling for unhandled background exceptions by performing the background work in a `Task` and then handling any exceptions in a continuation of that task that is explicitly scheduled to run on the main thread. There are additional options you can specify for the continuation, but this should cover your scenario.

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
    {
        // Do some work that may throw.
        // This code runs on the Threadpool.
        // Any exceptions will be propagated
        // to continuation tasks and awaiters
        // for observation.
        throw new StackOverflowException(); // :)
    }
).ContinueWith(
    (a) =>
    {
        // Handle your exception here.
        // This code runs on the thread
        // that started the worker task.
        if (a.Exception != null)
        {
            foreach (var ex in a.Exception.InnerExceptions)
            {
                // Try to handle or throw.
            }
        }
    },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.None,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
);
```

Another useful link is [MSDN's Asyncronous Programming Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152938.aspx). It identifies the 3 main ways to implement asynchronous operations in an application. Your current implementation sounds most similar to what the article calls EAP (Event-based Asynchronous Pattern).

I personally prefer TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern) which relies on the .NET 4.0 TPL (Task Parallel Library). It's well worth mastering due to the simplicity of its syntax and its extensive capabilities.

From MSDN:

- Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) pattern (also called the IAsyncResult pattern), where asynchronous operations require Begin and End methods (for example, BeginWrite and EndWrite for asynchronous write operations). This pattern is no longer recommended for new development. For more information, see Asynchronous Programming Model (APM).
- Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP), which requires a method that has the Async suffix, and also requires one or more events, event handler delegate types, and EventArg-derived types. EAP was introduced in the .NET Framework 2.0. It is no longer recommended for new development. For more information, see Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP).
- Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP), which uses a single method to represent the initiation and completion of an asynchronous operation. TAP was introduced in the .NET Framework 4 and is the recommended approach to asynchronous programming in the .NET Framework. For more information, see Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP).

Also, don't forget about the trusty [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. This class was a staple for me for a long time and although it has become somewhat deprecated by TAP, it will still get the job done and is very easy to understand and use.

```
// Create a new background worker.
var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

// Assign a delegate to perform the background work.
bgw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Runs in background thread. Unhandled exceptions
        // will cause the thread to terminate immediately.
        throw new StackOverflowException();
    };

// Assign a delegate to perform any cleanup/error handling/UI updating.
bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Runs in UI thread. Any unhandled exception that
        // occur in the background thread will be accessible
        // in the event arguments Error property.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Handle or rethrow.
        }
    };

// Start the background worker asynchronously.
bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Right now I'm on vacation so I don't really have the time to look at it. When I get back next week, I will look at it in detail and accept the answer if it solves the issue. :)

Comment: Yep, this is the elegant alternative to my ugly hack, thanks! Also, thanks for the oversight of different asynchronous programming patterns, I have started reading "C# in a nutshell", and will probably work my way through these in the coming time. :)